# Discord Bots are not recognized as Bots in Python code

Tags: python, discord.py, python-3.8

I am writing a discordbot bot the function user.bot isnt working correctly

```
@client.event
async on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
     if not user.bot:
          await client.wait_until_ready()
     try:
          channel = client.get_channel(welcome_channel_id)
              try:
                  await channel.send(message)
                  await reaction.remove(user)
              except Exception as e
                  raise e
              except Exception as e
                  raise e
```

Everything works accept the if statement, I create a message with a reaction with a bot but the bots reaction is removed.
I am using Python 3.8. If u need any extra information pls tell me.

Comment: `reaction.remove()` sure does sound like something that removes a reaction, right?

Comment: Yes but it still should not do it if the bot placed the reaction thats why there is a  `if not user.bot:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `try` block executed every time, after the if statement is evaluated.

I'm assuming it should only execute if the `if` statement evaluates to `true`:

```py
if not user.bot:
     await client.wait_until_ready()
     try:
          channel = client.get_channel(welcome_channel_id)
          await channel.send(message)
          await reaction.remove(user)
      except Exception as e
              raise e
```

But
`raise e` negates the whole point of using a try/catch block - it has no effect.

The above code is equivalent to

```py
if not user.bot:
     await client.wait_until_ready()
     channel = client.get_channel(welcome_channel_id)
     await channel.send(message)
     await reaction.remove(user)
```

Comment: Thank u for your fast help. It works :)

Comment: Consider accepting the answer if it works.

Comment: U where to fast I will as soon I can :)

Comment: Edited the answer to remove the redundant try/catch block. The try/catch block has no effect, though, as it just reraises every exception - it would work the same without it.

Comment: In a example code I had it was done that way so I thought it was better to do so thanks for correcting it :)